How to reduce the performance impact of For JSON Path
Both our frontend and backend utilize JSON and we have models which it binds to perfectly both frontend and backend. So staying completely in JSON format really makes life easier on me as a developer and reduces my need for Entity Framework for my development needs. However, from the various articles I have read there is a slight performance hit using For JSON but we have a query with about 2500 records that takes about 10-15 seconds which feels like something is wrong with our query. I have had to utilze pagination to make this more bearable for our frontend. We are newer to SQL (not programmers by trade but do use sql here and there) so we still have much to learn but this item is very crucial so I am hoping someone here might be able to pinpoint the issues with my query. I have been told do not let SQL server handle the deserializing and serializing but to be honest I had see posts of users with upwards of tens of thousands of records and their json code runs under a second yet which to me is acceptable and totally worth the performance hit if achievable. Please see the code below:
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date, ,>
-- Description: <Description, ,>
-- =============================================
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[A2Q_0171_RR_CertificationReviewModel_Browse_JSON](@StartingIndex int, @MaxRecords int)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
RETURN
(
select
    (
    select 
        JSON_QUERY ((select 
        --top (@MaxRecords)
            t1.MMCID,
            dbo.A2F_0012_ReturnMMCIDforDisplay(t1.MMCID) as MMCIDForDisplay
        FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER)) as MMCID,
        JSON_QUERY ((select distinct
            t2.STATE_ID,
            t2.ENTITY_NAME,
            t2.ENTITY_ABREVIATION,
            --t3.PROGRAM_SHORT_NAME as PROGRAM_CONCATENATE,
                (select distinct
                    t4.PROGRAM_NAME_DD,
                    t5.PROGRAM_NAME,
                    t5.PROGRAM_SHORT_NAME,
                    t5.PROGRAM_ACTIVE
                from
                    dbo.RRBaseProgramTBL as t4,
                    dbo.RRProgramListTBL as t5
                where
                    t2.STATE_ID = t5.STATE_ID
                    AND t1.MMCID = t4.MMCID
                    AND t4.PROGRAM_NAME_DD = t5.PROGRAM_DD
                FOR JSON PATH) as PROGRAM_INFO
            --dbo.A2F_0013_RR_ConcatenateProgramsByMMCID() as t3
            --AND t1.MMCID = t3.MMCID
        from
            dbo.USStateListTBL as t2
        where
            t1.STATE_ID = t2.STATE_ID
        FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER)) as STATE_INFORMATION,
        JSON_QUERY ((select 
            t1.OLD_TRACKER_NAME,
            t1.NEW_TRACKER_NAME
        FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES)) as TRACKER_NAME,
        JSON_QUERY ((select 
            t1.RATING_PERIOD_BEGINS,
            format(t1.RATING_PERIOD_BEGINS, 'MM/dd/yyyy') as RATING_PERIOD_BEGINS_FORMATTED,
            t1.RATING_PERIOD_ENDS,
            format(t1.RATING_PERIOD_ENDS, 'MM/dd/yyyy') as RATING_PERIOD_ENDS_FORMATTED
        FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER)) as RATING_PERIOD,
        JSON_QUERY ((select 
            t1.CERTIFICATION_DATE,
            format(t1.CERTIFICATION_DATE, 'MM/dd/yyyy') as CERTIFICATION_DATE_FORMATTED
        FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER)) as CERTIFICATION_DATE,
        (select distinct
            t7.FIRST_NAME,
            t7.LAST_NAME,
            t7.INTERNAL_USER_NUMBER,
            t8.User_Role_Description,
            t8.User_Role_Description_abbrev
        from
            dbo.RRRoleAssignmentMMCIDTBL as t6,
            dbo.UsersAccountsTBL as t7,
            dbo.UserRoleDefinitionsTBL as t8
        where
            t1.MMCID = t6.MMCID
            AND (t6.JOB_ASSIGNMENT = 1 OR t6.JOB_ASSIGNMENT = 2 OR t6.JOB_ASSIGNMENT = 5)
            AND t6.USER_ASSIGNMENT = t7.INTERNAL_USER_NUMBER
            AND t6.JOB_ASSIGNMENT = t8.User_Role_Number_DD
        FOR JSON PATH, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES) as RATE_REVIEWERS,
        JSON_QUERY((select distinct
            --t9.Signing_Actuary as SIGNING_ACTUARY_CONCATENATED,
            t9.ACTUARIAL_FIRM_DD,
            t10.FIRM_NAME
        from
            dbo.ActuarySigningTBL as t9,
            dbo.ActuarialFirmTBL as t10
        where
            t1.MMCID = t9.MMCID
            AND t9.ACTUARIAL_FIRM_DD = t10.FIRM_DD_NUMBER
        FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES)) as ACTUARIAL_FIRM,
        (select
            (t11.FIRST_NAME + ' ' + t11.LAST_NAME) as NAME,
            t11.INTERNAL_USER_NUMBER
        from
            dbo.ActuarySigningTBL as t16,
            dbo.UsersAccountsTBL as t11
        where
            t1.MMCID = t16.MMCID
            AND t16.SIGNING_ACTUARY_DD = t11.INTERNAL_USER_NUMBER
        FOR JSON PATH, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES) as SIGNING_ACTUARY,
        JSON_QUERY((select
            t1.REVIEW_TYPE_DD,
            t12.ReviewTypeDescription
        FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER)) as REVIEW_TYPE,
        JSON_QUERY((select 
            t13.STATE_SUBMISSION_DATE,
            format(t13.STATE_SUBMISSION_DATE, 'MM/dd/yyyy') as STATE_SUBMISSION_DATE_FORMATTED,
            t13.DMCP_SUBMISSION_DATE,
            format(t13.DMCP_SUBMISSION_DATE, 'MM/dd/yyyy') as DMCP_SUBMISSION_DATE_FORMATTED
        FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES)) as SUBMISSION_DATE,
        JSON_QUERY((select 
            t1.ACTUARIAL_REVIEW_STATUS_DD,
            t14.DISPLAY,
            t13.OACT_MEMO_DATE,
            format(t13.OACT_MEMO_DATE, 'MM/dd/yyyy') as OACT_MEMO_DATE_FORMATTED
        FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES)) as OACT_REVIEW_STATUS,
        JSON_QUERY((select
            t1.DMCP_REVIEW_STATUS_DD,
            t15.DISPLAY,
            t13.DMCP_RECOMMENDATION_DATE,
            format(t13.DMCP_RECOMMENDATION_DATE, 'MM/dd/yyyy') as DMCP_RECOMMENDATION_DATE_FORMATTED,
            t13.DMCP_RECOMMENDATION_COMMENT
        FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES)) as DMCP_REVIEW_STATUS,
        JSON_QUERY((select
            t13.RISK_MITIGATION,
            t13.RATE_RANGES,
            t13.REVISED_CERT,
            t13.REVISED_CERT_DATE,
            format(t13.REVISED_CERT_DATE, 'MM/dd/yyyy') as REVISED_CERT_DATE_FORMATTED
        FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES)) as DMCP_ADDITIONAL_INFO
    from
        dbo.RateReviewBaseTBL as t1,
        dbo.RRReviewTypeTBL as t12,
        dbo.DMCPAdditionalTrackerInformationTBL as t13,
        dbo.ActuarialReviewStatusDisplay_TBL as t14,
        dbo.RRDMCPReviewStatusTBL as t15
    where
        t1.REVIEW_TYPE_DD = t12.ReviewTypeDD
        AND t1.MMCID = t13.MMCID
        AND t1.ACTUARIAL_REVIEW_STATUS_DD = t14.ACTUARIAL_REVIEW_STATUS_DD
        AND t1.DMCP_REVIEW_STATUS_DD = t15.DMCP_REVIEW_STATUS_DD
        --AND t1.MMCID >= (select max(t16.MMCID) from
        --              (select top (@StartingIndex) MMCID
        --              from dbo.RateReviewBaseTBL
        --              order by MMCID) as t16)
    order by t1.MMCID
    OFFSET (@StartingIndex - 1) ROWS
    FETCH NEXT @MaxRecords ROWS ONLY
    FOR JSON PATH, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES
    ) as DATA,
    @StartingIndex as STARTING_INDEX,
    (select count(MMCID) from dbo.RateReviewBaseTBL) as TOTAL_ROWS,
    @MaxRecords as MAX_RECORDS_PER_QUERY
FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES
)
END
GO

If there is any additional information I should provide to help debug this I will gladly add it.

How is this function being called? Is it against a dataset, or just on it's own? SELECT dbo.YourFunction(SomeCol,AnotherCol) FROM dbo.SomeTable; vs SELECT dbo.YourFunction(1,10);

I call it "select dbo.A2Q_0171_RR_CertificationReviewModel_Browse_JSON(@StartingIndex, @EndingIndex)" where StartingIndex and EndingIndex are defined by my api for pagination. We store it as a scalar function so its just a one liner in my api returning a string which is then deserialized on the backend and automatically binds to my models in place.

Can you Paste the Plan?

Also some required reading: Bad Habits to Kick : Using old-style JOINs & Bad Habits to Kick : Using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)

Its very neat to see they have the ability to post the xml. Here is a link it estimated plan from Azure Data Studio:  https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Skz4HTqJ0 and thank you for the readings. I will check this out for sure.

I see nothing but scans in there (and one seek). Do you not have any relevant indexes on your tables? That's the likely problem here.

We do not use indexes. Just recently learned that term this morning trying to figure this out.

"We do not use indexes." Well there's your problem. If none of your database is indexed then you need to start doing so. What you need to index is likely to be far too broad for a single [so] question.

What do you think we could get our query time to if its currently at 8 seconds and we add indexes? I know thats a very general question but when I was researching it earlier today it seemed somewhat complex so curious of the gains before really investing the time to learn and implement. Also I couldnt find anything that related to indexing and JSON for sql. I would note that if we didnt do JSON we could probably get this query done in 2 seconds so I thought the problem led back to the For JSON .

So much bad stuff in  this query: Should use explicit joins instead of comma-joins. CONVERT instead of FORMAT, proper table aliases instead of t1, t2, t3. Use of DISTINCT. Subqueries expecting a single result without a TOP 1 or unique ID filter. Subqueries and WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER instead of just using JSON paths in the column names.

@Thom A we have added indexes and that has reduced the time down to 3 seconds. For now that seems acceptable though definitely more room for improvement. The issue is 3 seconds is what the sql server takes to do it. Getting the data from the sql server with my dapper query takes 25 seconds. Is there something we need to do to the data before it is returned to backend? Serialize it in sql server somehow to reduce the total data sent/returned?

There are a number of things for you to think about.

Firstly, you query can be massively simplified by using JSON paths as column names. This works any time you have a scalar object property (ie not an array, using WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER). This allows you to remove most of the subqueries and the JSON_QUERY calls.
The double subquery against UsersAccountsTBL could probably be combined in some way, but I don't know your schema or requirements.
Use CONVERT with a style number, instead of the slow FORMAT function, if possible.

CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.A2Q_0171_RR_CertificationReviewModel_Browse_JSON
  (@StartingIndex int, @MaxRecords int)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
RETURN
(
  select
    (
      select
        rrb.MMCID AS [MMCID.MMCID],
        dbo.A2F_0012_ReturnMMCIDforDisplay(rrb.MMCID) as [MMCID.MMCIDForDisplay],
        usstate.STATE_ID AS [STATE_INFORMATION.STATE_ID],
        usstate.ENTITY_NAME AS [STATE_INFORMATION.ENTITY_NAME],
        usstate.ENTITY_ABREVIATION AS [STATE_INFORMATION.ENTITY_ABREVIATION],
        (
            select distinct
              bp.PROGRAM_NAME_DD,
              pl.PROGRAM_NAME,
              pl.PROGRAM_SHORT_NAME,
              pl.PROGRAM_ACTIVE
            from
                dbo.RRBaseProgramTBL as bp
            join
                dbo.RRProgramListTBL as pl
                ON bp.PROGRAM_NAME_DD = pl.PROGRAM_DD
            where
                usstate.STATE_ID = pl.STATE_ID
                AND rrb.MMCID = bp.MMCID
            FOR JSON PATH
        ) as [STATE_INFORMATION.PROGRAM_INFO],
        rrb.OLD_TRACKER_NAME AS [TRACKER_NAME.OLD_TRACKER_NAME],
        rrb.NEW_TRACKER_NAME AS [TRACKER_NAME.NEW_TRACKER_NAME],
        rrb.RATING_PERIOD_BEGINS AS [RATING_PERIOD.RATING_PERIOD_BEGINS],
        convert(date, rrb.RATING_PERIOD_BEGINS, 101) as [RATING_PERIOD.RATING_PERIOD_BEGINS_FORMATTED],
        rrb.RATING_PERIOD_ENDS AS [RATING_PERIOD.RATING_PERIOD_ENDS],
        convert(date, rrb.RATING_PERIOD_ENDS, 101) as [RATING_PERIOD.RATING_PERIOD_ENDS_FORMATTED],
        rrb.CERTIFICATION_DATE AS [CERTIFICATION_DATE.CERTIFICATION_DATE],
        convert(date, rrb.CERTIFICATION_DATE, 101) as [CERTIFICATION_DATE.CERTIFICATION_DATE_FORMATTED],
        (
          select distinct
            ua.FIRST_NAME,
            ua.LAST_NAME,
            ua.INTERNAL_USER_NUMBER,
            urd.User_Role_Description,
            urd.User_Role_Description_abbrev
          from
              dbo.RRRoleAssignmentMMCIDTBL as ram
          join
              dbo.UsersAccountsTBL as ua
              on ram.USER_ASSIGNMENT = ua.INTERNAL_USER_NUMBER
          join
              dbo.UserRoleDefinitionsTBL as urd
              on ram.JOB_ASSIGNMENT = urd.User_Role_Number_DD
          where
              rrb.MMCID = ram.MMCID
              AND ram.JOB_ASSIGNMENT IN (1, 2, 5)
          FOR JSON PATH, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES
        ) as RATE_REVIEWERS,
        acts.ACTUARIAL_FIRM_DD AS [ACTUARIAL_FIRM.ACTUARIAL_FIRM_DD],
        acts.FIRM_NAME AS [ACTUARIAL_FIRM.FIRM_NAME]
        (
          select
            ua.FIRST_NAME + ' ' + ua.LAST_NAME as NAME,
            ua.INTERNAL_USER_NUMBER
          from
              dbo.UsersAccountsTBL as ua
          where
              acts.SIGNING_ACTUARY_DD = ua.INTERNAL_USER_NUMBER
              AND rrb.MMCID = acts.MMCID
          FOR JSON PATH, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES
        ) as SIGNING_ACTUARY,
        rrb.REVIEW_TYPE_DD AS [REVIEW_TYPE.REVIEW_TYPE_DD],
        rrvt.ReviewTypeDescription AS [REVIEW_TYPE.ReviewTypeDescription]
        dati.STATE_SUBMISSION_DATE AS [SUBMISSION_DATE.STATE_SUBMISSION_DATE],
        convert(date, dati.STATE_SUBMISSION_DATE, 101) AS [SUBMISSION_DATE.STATE_SUBMISSION_DATE_FORMATTED],
        dati.DMCP_SUBMISSION_DATE AS [SUBMISSION_DATE.DMCP_SUBMISSION_DATE],
        convert(date, dati.DMCP_SUBMISSION_DATE, 101) AS [SUBMISSION_DATE.DMCP_SUBMISSION_DATE_FORMATTED],
        rrb.ACTUARIAL_REVIEW_STATUS_DD AS [OACT_REVIEW_STATUS.ACTUARIAL_REVIEW_STATUS_DD],
        arsd.DISPLAY AS [OACT_REVIEW_STATUS.DISPLAY],
        dati.OACT_MEMO_DATE AS [OACT_REVIEW_STATUS.OACT_MEMO_DATE].
        convert(date, dati.OACT_MEMO_DATE, 101) AS [OACT_REVIEW_STATUS.OACT_MEMO_DATE_FORMATTED],
        rrb.DMCP_REVIEW_STATUS_DD AS [DMCP_REVIEW_STATUS.DMCP_REVIEW_STATUS_DD],
        rrdrs.DISPLAY AS [DMCP_REVIEW_STATUS.DISPLAY],
        dati.DMCP_RECOMMENDATION_DATE AS [DMCP_REVIEW_STATUS.DMCP_RECOMMENDATION_DATE],
        convert(date, dati.DMCP_RECOMMENDATION_DATE, 101) AS [DMCP_REVIEW_STATUS.DMCP_RECOMMENDATION_DATE_FORMATTED],
        dati.DMCP_RECOMMENDATION_COMMENT AS [DMCP_REVIEW_STATUS.,
        dati.RISK_MITIGATION AS [DMCP_ADDITIONAL_INFO.RISK_MITIGATION],
        dati.RATE_RANGES AS [DMCP_ADDITIONAL_INFO.RATE_RANGES],
        dati.REVISED_CERT AS [DMCP_ADDITIONAL_INFO.REVISED_CERT],
        dati.REVISED_CERT_DATE AS [DMCP_ADDITIONAL_INFO.REVISED_CERT_DATE],
        convert(date, dati.REVISED_CERT_DATE, 101) AS [DMCP_ADDITIONAL_INFO.REVISED_CERT_DATE_FORMATTED],
      from
          dbo.RateReviewBaseTBL as rrb
      join
          dbo.RRReviewTypeTBL as rrvt
          on rrb.REVIEW_TYPE_DD = rrvt.ReviewTypeDD
      join
          dbo.DMCPAdditionalTrackerInformationTBL as dati,
          on rrb.MMCID = dati.MMCID
      join
          dbo.ActuarialReviewStatusDisplay_TBL as arsd,
          on rrb.ACTUARIAL_REVIEW_STATUS_DD = arsd.ACTUARIAL_REVIEW_STATUS_DD
      join
          dbo.RRDMCPReviewStatusTBL as rrdrs
          on rrb.DMCP_REVIEW_STATUS_DD = rrdrs.DMCP_REVIEW_STATUS_DD
      left join
          dbo.USStateListTBL as usstate
          on rrb.STATE_ID = usstate.STATE_ID
      left join
      (
          select distinct
              acts.ACTUARIAL_FIRM_DD,
              actf.FIRM_NAME
          from
              dbo.ActuarySigningTBL as acts
          join
              dbo.ActuarialFirmTBL as actf
              on acts.ACTUARIAL_FIRM_DD = actf.FIRM_DD_NUMBER
      ) as acts
          ON rrb.MMCID = acts.MMCID
      order by rrb.MMCID
      OFFSET (@StartingIndex - 1) ROWS
      FETCH NEXT @MaxRecords ROWS ONLY
      FOR JSON PATH, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES
    ) as DATA,
    @StartingIndex as STARTING_INDEX,
    (select count(*) from dbo.RateReviewBaseTBL) as TOTAL_ROWS,
    @MaxRecords as MAX_RECORDS_PER_QUERY
  FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES
);
END;


You should also seriously think about those DISTINCTs, why are they there? Are you getting duplicates, if so, why? Perhaps your join conditions are not correct, or you need some kind of row-numbering solution.
The ORDER BY... OFFSET paging is itself an issue. Paging by row-number is very inefficient as you need to scan all previous rows. Consider Keyset Pagination.
Getting the total count is extra work that is probably not necessary.
You appear not to have proper indexing. You need to look at your query and decide what indexes will support the query. Look at join and filtering conditions.


The acts table alias in your code doesnt seem accessible outside of the parenthesis and is drawing errors. Was that your intention?

Sorry fixed that up now.

So acts is still not accessible in the other spots its used unfortunately. Keeps drawing an error on its use.

I also think the shape of the data is going to change based on how you have it. Our json from the original query above looks like this [{MMCID : {MMCID: 1, MMCIDForDisplay: "va-001"}, STATE_INFORMATION: {STATE_ID: 1, ENTITY_NAME:"VA", PROGRAM_INFO:[{{PROGRAM_ID: 5,}]}},.....]. We have a lot of nested JSON objects in our records basically so thats why we default to using FOR JSON PATH so much. But. yours doesnt seem like it would create those JSON nodes so Id be curious how your code would even work. I appreicate it though.

So it depends if you need an array or not. If you need an array for multiple objects nested inside then you will need a subquery and another FOR JSON. But if it's just a single object then you don't need to do that, you can use JSON paths in the column names as I have shown. Please try it and you will see what I mean. See also https://dbfiddle.uk/A9V6XSXd

When I get back to work Monday il definitely give this a shot. My issue though was even tho the query got down to 3 seconds in the sql server. For some reason on the c# side it takes 25 seconds for the dapper query to finish executing it . Surprised that 2400 records would be that much data to cause a 25 second delay for it to run/pull the sql data. It’s all hosted in the same data center too so not a network issue.

And yes a lot are single objects so that is a very useful trick you have shown. Is that considered more performant?

Yes, I would imagine so, much less processing. usually not the size of the data actually retrieved but the steps it needs to go through (indexes, joins etc). Examine the query plan to find out.

Both our sql server and our backend are 8 core 16gb so should be plenty powerful enough. I mean why would the sql execute in 3 seconds on sql server but when running the query on a backend change it to 21 seconds. Baffles me.
